# why translate functions are seen in tlb.cc in gem5 for any architecture?

Tags: c++, gem5

Firstly, why a TLB code should have translate functions? Aren't they supposed to just index using the virtual address and give the corresponding matching physical address.

Secondly, what does the names translateInt, finalizePhysical suggest about the happening in their codes.

And finally, the intuition behind the parameters to the function req->setpaddr() for different cases, like multiplying with MiscReg as in the case when the prefix matches IntAddrPrefixMSR.

```
else if (prefix == IntAddrPrefixMSR) {
    vaddr = (vaddr >> 3) & ~IntAddrPrefixMask;
    req->setFlags(Request::MMAPPED_IPR);

    MiscRegIndex regNum;
    if (!msrAddrToIndex(regNum, vaddr))
        return std::make_shared<GeneralProtection>(0);

    //The index is multiplied by the size of a MiscReg so that
    //any memory dependence calculations will not see these as
    //overlapping.
    req->setPaddr((Addr)regNum * sizeof(MiscReg));
    return NoFault;
} else if (prefix == IntAddrPrefixIO) {
    // TODO If CPL > IOPL or in virtual mode, check the I/O permission
    // bitmap in the TSS.

    Addr IOPort = vaddr & ~IntAddrPrefixMask;
    // Make sure the address fits in the expected 16 bit IO address
    // space.
    assert(!(IOPort & ~0xFFFF));
    if (IOPort == 0xCF8 && req->getSize() == 4) {
        req->setFlags(Request::MMAPPED_IPR);
        req->setPaddr(MISCREG_PCI_CONFIG_ADDRESS * sizeof(MiscReg));
    } else if ((IOPort & ~mask(2)) == 0xCFC) {
        req->setFlags(Request::UNCACHEABLE | Request::STRICT_ORDER);
        Addr configAddress =
            tc->readMiscRegNoEffect(MISCREG_PCI_CONFIG_ADDRESS);
        if (bits(configAddress, 31, 31)) {
            req->setPaddr(PhysAddrPrefixPciConfig |
                    mbits(configAddress, 30, 2) |
                    (IOPort & mask(2)));
        } else {
            req->setPaddr(PhysAddrPrefixIO | IOPort);
        }
    } else {
        req->setFlags(Request::UNCACHEABLE | Request::STRICT_ORDER);
        req->setPaddr(PhysAddrPrefixIO | IOPort);
    }
    return NoFault;
```

Comment: I have edited the question by making my questions a bit more ordered. If not for the other questions, can anybody just tell me what the name translateInt or finalizePhysical suggest???